# Explicit formula for interpolating polynomial

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

$a\in(0,1)$ is fixed.

$M\in\Bbb Z_{>1}$ is fixed.

What is $f(x)$ given that $$f(0)=0\mbox{, }f(M)=1+a\mbox{, }f(1)=1-a$$$$\mbox{ }f(x)\in(1-a,1+a)\mbox{, }\forall x\in(1,M)?$$

What is $g(x)$ given that $$g(1)=1\mbox{, }g(0)=-a\mbox{, }g(1-M)=a$$$$\mbox{ }f(x)\in(-a,+a)\mbox{, }\forall x\in(1-M,0)?$$

What is $\mathsf{deg}(f(x)),\mathsf{deg}(g(x))$?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: My best is that for small $a$ and large $M$ you will need higher and higher degree. This must be somehow related to Tchebychev interpolation.

Comment: Up to infinity.

Comment: true but with fixed M and fixed a?

Comment: @Turbo It depends on $a$ and $M$, and I wouldn't be surprised if the maximal $a$ for fixed $M$ and degree is the root of some high-degree polynomial (so that explicit formulas will be unhelpful)

Comment: @MarioCarneiro please write as answer whatever you know is reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a complete answer, but some observations.

For the first part, note that $f(x)$ is of the form $f(x)=xh(x)$. Now, $f(x)$ cannot be $0$ for any real $x$ for $x\in (1,M)$. So the degree of $f$ is of the form $2m+n+1$ where $m$ is the number of complex roots of $f$, $n$ is the number of real roots of $f$, if any, in $(0,1)$.